# Help understanding proof for additivity of Lebesgue outer measure for open sets

Tags: measure-theory

I’m reading the proof for the following lemma regarding the additivity of the Lebesgue outer measure:

> Suppose $A$ and $G$ are disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $G$ is
> open. Then $$|A∪G| = |A|+|G|.$$
>
> Proof: We can assume that $|G| < ∞$ because otherwise both $|A ∪ G|$
> and $|A| + |G| $ equal $∞$.
>
> Subadditivity (see 2.8) implies that $|A ∪ G| ≤ |A| + |G|$. Thus we
> need to prove the inequality only in the other direction.
>
> First consider the case where $G = (a,b)$ for some $a,b ∈ \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$. We can assume that $a,b \notin A $ (because changing a set by at most two points does not change its outer measure). Let $I_1, I_2, . . .$ be a sequence of open intervals whose union contains $A ∪ G$. For each $n ∈ \mathbb{Z}^+$, let
>
> $$J_n = I_n ∩(−∞,a), K_n = I_n ∩(a,b), L_n = I_n ∩(b,∞).$$
>
> Then
>
> $$\mathcal{l}(I_n)= \mathcal{l}(J_n)+ \mathcal{l}(K_n)+ \mathcal{l}(L_n) $$
>
> Now $J_1, L_1, J_2, L_2, . . .$ is a sequence of open intervals whose union contains $A$ and $K_1, K_2, . . .$ is a sequence of open
> intervals whose union contains $G$. Thus
>
> $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\mathcal{l}(I_n)}=
>  \sum^\infty_{n=1}{(\mathcal{l}(J_n)+\mathcal{l}(K_n))} +
>  \sum^\infty_{n=1}{\mathcal{l}(L_n)} ≥ |A| + |G|.$$
>
> The inequality above implies that $|A ∪ G| ≥ |A| + |G|$, completing
> the proof that $|A ∪ G| = |A| + |G|$ in this special case.

Source: *Measure, Integration, and Real Analysis* by Sheldon Axler.

I’m having trouble with how the final inequality implies $|A ∪ G| = |A| + |G|$. $|A ∪ G|$ is by definition the infimum of $\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\mathcal{l}(I_n)}$ over all possible open covers $\{I_n\}$, and $|A ∪ G|\le \sum^\infty_{n=1}{\mathcal{l}(I_n)}$ for any $\{I_n\}$, by the definition of a lower bound. Thus the last part of the proof amounts to saying $|A ∪ G|\le \sum^\infty_{n=1}{\mathcal{l}(I_n)}$ and $|A| + |G|\le \sum^\infty_{n=1}{\mathcal{l}(I_n)}$, which does not allow us to conclude $|A\cup G|=|A|+|G|$.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is shown that $\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\mathcal{l}(I_n)} ≥ |A| + |G|$ for any cover of $A \cup G$ by open intervals $(I_n)$.
This implies that the infimum of the sums in the left side is also $\ge |A|+|G|$, which means that $|A\cup G| \ge |A|+|G|$. The reverse inequality always holds.

[If each element of  a set $S$ of real numbers is $\ge a$ then $\inf S \ge a$].